# Is sequel pro available for AWS RDS with a private subnet?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, rds

I create MariaDB on AWS RDS. At this time, I put the RDS on the private subnet, and the connection was successful in phpmyadmin on ec2.
And I create an instance that Bastion host Instance, and install MariaDB. So I can manage DB on terminal(mac).

And now I want to manage my DB easily with sequel pro, but of course I could not connect to RDS with endpoint/user/password.

What I hava to do for access RDS using Sequel pro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can connect the RDS using Sequel pro via an SSH tunnel through your Bastion host.